# Error while exacting values of <a> tags - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using `BeautifulSoup` for web scraping.
I have this code to extract the values of `a` tags but it does not seem to work. It shows error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Here is code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.example.com"

page  = requests.get(url).text
soup_expatistan = BeautifulSoup(page)

expatistan_table = soup_expatistan.find("div", id="country-box")

expatistan_titles = expatistan_table.find_all("ul", class_="unstyled flat")[1]
#print (expatistan_titles)
for expatistan_title in expatistan_titles:
     print (expatistan_title.find("a").text) """ Error on this line """
```

I have verified `expatistan_title` output that contains:

```
<li class=""> <a href="http://www.wotif.com/AR" class="multiselect__option js-country-selector " data-id="AR">Argentina</a>
</li>
 <li class=""> <a href="http://www.wotif.com/AU" class="multiselect__option js-country-selector " data-id="AU">Australia</a>
 </li>
 <li class=""> <a href="http://www.wotif.com/AT" class="multiselect__option js-country-selector " data-id="AT">Austria</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: find() returns index of found object, not object.

Comment: it displays a different html contents for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it is because the OP replaced his real url with an `example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expatistan_titles = expatistan_table.find_all("ul", class_="unstyled flat")[1]
```

leads to `expatistan_titles` being a single element, not a list. Then you iterate over it char by char, call [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) on a each which return an `int` position of a substring in a string. And, of course, there is no `text` attribute on an `int` object.

Let it be:

```
expatistan_titles = expatistan_table.find_all("ul", class_="unstyled flat")[1]
for expatistan_title in expatistan_titles.find_all('li'):
     print (expatistan_title.find("a").text)
```

Besides, you can simplify the code by using [`CSS Selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), just 2 lines:

```
for link in soup.select('div#country-box ul.unstyled.flat li a'):
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: I used index because I had 2 `ul`s there and I wanted to get 2nd one...
As I said ... I have already got `li`s and I need to get values of `a`s inside them

Comment: @Umair then, you probably meant `for expatistan_title in  expatistan_titles.find_all('li'):`.

Comment: `for expatistan_title in expatistan_titles.find_all('li'):` ...

Worked ... thanks

Comment: @Umair ok, I've edited the answer accordingly. Does the `CSS selector` option work for you?

Comment: in the CSS SELECTORS , how can I get the 2nd occurence of `unstyled flat` ... not the first one

Comment: @Umair ah, gotcha, give a try to `div#country-box ul.unstyled.flat:nth-child(2) li a`.

Comment: @Umair thanks, did the `div#country-box ul.unstyled.flat:nth-child(2) li a` work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64414/discussion-between-umair-and-alecxe).